# Letter 'c' is randomly inputted by dragging mouse on Mac

Tags: mouse, parallels-desktop

I'm running Windows 8.1 on Parallels 10.4.0 for Mac. My issue is that every time I double click my mouse there is a 'c' character randomly inputted, which is very annoying. There is a solution from [this link](http://kb.parallels.com/123723) talking about the same issue, but I am unable to get this to work.

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

[Update] I found that the same issue exists when I use mathematica on OS X. When I drag click and drag the mouse, there will be an 'c' inputted. I doubt that it may be some software from OS X that caused the problem...

Comment: Well...this is a stupid bug from a dictionary software called Youdao. When I turn on the screen translation, the problem appears. I know few people use this software but in case someone met with the same problem, I choose not to delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a dictionary app called Youdao. I solved it by disabling the features named "Screen Translation 屏幕取词" & "Selected Translation 划词翻译" of YoudaoDict.